# How to find IP address of the virtual machine running ?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtual, openstack, vnc

I'm trying to create a cloud image using this document [docs.openstack.org/image-guide/content/section_fedora-example.html](http://image-openstack) , so basically seeing the reference i'm creating an image in a Virtual Machine , but after the image is created , i need the IP address to ssh ( access ) into the instance created in the Virtual Machine . I have virsh installed

I can see the virtual instance running by 
  #virsh list   -- I get to see my instance running

I need the IP address of the instance created , but i'm not able to find appropriate method / command to get the IP addres of the instance .

Comment: have you tried running ifconfig on the console of the virtual machine?

Comment: login to virtual machine, open console and type `ifconfig`

Comment: @MichaelDibbets Yes , when i go into console using 'virsh console' command , it says " press ^] to escape"  and hangs there :/

Comment: are the network drivers initialised? if you type ping 127.0.0.1 does the loopback work? can you ping any other server on the network?

Comment: @MichaelDibbets Ping 127.0.0.1 in the instance you mean ? I'm not able  to login to that machine , and I don't know what network drivers configurations in the VM to be done :/

Comment: ssh is closed by default on a new installation, sometimes not even installed. just open the image localy set it up correctly

Comment: @MichaelDibbets well the image is up , i mean the instance , when i log into it gets hung , do you have documentation or commands to set up network configurations ?